Tests files fail unless I run one test file at a time
I'm testing my routes in an express app using supertest and jest. I have two separate test files, userRouter.test.js and boardRouter.test.js. I use the following setup file to initialize my database.
// initialize test database with info
beforeEach(async () => {
  try {
    const [user, userTwo] = await Promise.all([
      client.users.create({
        data: {
          username: "foo",
          email: "bar@baz.com",
          pw: await bcrypt.hash("password", 10),
        },
      }),
      await client.users.create({
        data: {
          username: "bar",
          email: "foo@bar.com",
          pw: await bcrypt.hash("password", 10),
        },
      }),
    ]);

    await Promise.all([
      client.boards.create({
        data: {
          name: "one",
          creator_id: user.id,
          created_at: new Date(200000000000),
          members: {
            connect: user,
          },
        },
      }),
      client.boards.create({
        data: {
          name: "two",
          creator_id: userTwo.id,
          created_at: new Date(300000000000),
          members: {
            connect: userTwo,
          },
        },
      }),
      client.boards.create({
        data: {
          name: "three",
          creator_id: user.id,
          created_at: new Date(400000000000),
          members: {
            connect: [user, userTwo],
          },
        },
      }),
    ]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return;
  }
});

// remove files from test database
afterEach(async () => {
  await client.boards.deleteMany({});
  await client.users.deleteMany({});
  await client.posts.deleteMany({});
});

Everything's fine when I run one test file at a time. But if I run both test files at the same time, I start running into errors. Prisma will give me unique constraint errors because my beforeEach function is apparently running before another test has ended.
I would only seed the database once. But some tests insert data into the tables as well, which could interfere with the results of the other tests (a test that expects a list of boards may fail if another test checks to see if the user can make create a board.
I am unsure how to proceed here. Should I place all of my tests in only one file and forego testing the individual routes?

Read MVCC in particular Transaction Isolation. That will explain the why of the errors, then you work on the how of correcting them.

@AdrianKlaver, forgive me but I'm not entirely sure how this will solve my problem. I don't want my beforeEach to seed the database concurrently in the first place. I want to seed the database before each individual test, and then clear it so that the next test can run without any side effects from the previous database.

Then don't run the tests concurrently - Jest parallelises them across the available workers, which you can limit with https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--maxworkersnumstring
